# How to trigger event on current thread's target object

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

In my use case I have JMSReader which is running as a Thread, picks up message from a queue, and then uses a JMSWriter object to write to a destination. 
What is the best way for the JMSWriter object to trigger an event, which will cause the JMSReader to update its state.
Note: The JMSWriter's current thread target is the JMSReader. I am using java. I am unable to get a handle to the JMSWriter current thread target object (JMSReader ).

The thread is running as Reader, its target object is JMSReader. It uses JMSWriter to write to a topic. How can I get JMSWriter to trigger an event on the specific JMSReader. They are both under the Reader thread.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a callback method for getting the result of the newly created thread by passing the current object to the thread.

Then with-in thread, after completing execution, you can set appropriate state[field] in that object & again call the callback method. Provided pseudo code below.

**Thread_1**

```
Thread_2 t = new Thread_2(callBackObj);

//-- Start thread
```

**Thread_2**

```
callBackObj.setState(STOPPED); //-- Similarly for other properties

callBackObj.callBack();
```

---

Else, you can try setting **correlation-id** & **reply-to** options, it might help to track the required message information.